# How to get data from database with specific combination of name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3

I am working on ruby on rails project and I need to get data from the database with a specific combination like `c*_c*_othername` * can be numbered 1,2,3 etc like `c1_c1_anystring`. Prefix c is fixed for all time.
I am trying with following code but it's not working

```
Topic.where("name like ?", "%c*_c*_*%")
```

Comment: I believe it is not about Rails but database, you can solve it using DB regexps. Which DB do you use?

Comment: @Yakov postgresql database

Comment: There is no * (asterisk) sign in `LIKE` expression, it belongs to regular expression and `SIMILAR TO` or `NOT SIMILAR TO` expressions. You have to use these symbols _ (underscore) which leads to one any symbol and % (percent) symbol which leads to  any sequence of zero or more characters. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-LIKE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need [`SIMILAR TO`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/functions-matching.html)

Try the below:

```
Topic.where('name SIMILAR TO ?', "%c\\d\\_c\\d\\_%")
```

If you are accepting more than one digits, Use the below pattern

```
Topic.where('name SIMILAR TO ?', "%c\\d+\\_c\\d+\\_%")
```

If you don't like escaping underscores, You can also use `~` for pattern matching as mentioned in the docs:

```
Topic.where('name ~ ?', ".*c\\d+_c\\d+_.*")
```

> `\d` in the regular expression matches digits from 0 to 9

> c*_c*_othername the othername is not compulsory. Some time the name is c5_c6 only so this type of names I also want to get

Please try the below pattern

```
 Topic.where('name ~ ?', ".*c\\d+_c\\d+(_.*)?$")
```

Comment: Thankyou you for your answer ... Its very close what I need..... `c*_c*_othername`  the othername is not compulsory. Some time the name is c5_c6 only so this type of names I also want to get

Comment: @VarinderSohal Updated the answer with another pattern, please check now

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
Topic.where("name like 'c_\\_c_\\_%'")
```

Comment: Thankyou for your answer but it also return c1-c2_test . I just need only c1_c2_something

Comment: @VarinderSohal I have updated my answer, can you try it again?

Comment: This will return records with data like  `cd_cd_anystring` since underscore in the pattern matches any single character;

Comment: @user11350468, yeah, I see, my your comment would help :D